# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'x' does not exist in type (prisma)

Tags: next.js, prisma, vercel

Recently I've tried to add two new items to one of my tables in my Prisma schema.
After I update my database (using Prisma DB push) and try to .create a new data for my table I face some issues. On my localhost the project is fine and all the APIs are working correctly. but when I deploy the project on the server (using Vercel) it throws an error:

[image]

this is my schema :
[image]

this is my saveFormData.ts ( the API for saving data ) :
[image]

p.s: I'm using next.js + Prisma :

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is npx prisma generate command a part of your build script?
You can have a look at this build script as a reference: https://github.com/prisma/deployment-example-vercel/blob/main/package.json#L13

Comment: after I saw your answer I added npx prisma generate and now I'm facing this error :
`

Error: P3005
18:01:21.525 |  
18:01:21.525 | The database schema is not empty. Read more about how to baseline an existing production database: https://pris.ly/d/migrate-baseline
18:01:21.525 |  
18:01:21.552 | Error: Command "npm run vercel-build" exited with 1

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it by adding some script to my package.json file :

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "vercel-build": "prisma generate && prisma db push && next build",
    "prisma:generate": "prisma generate"
  },
```

p.s: you can use  `migrate deploy` instead of  prisma db push

Comment: This saved me. I was having the same issue when i would deploy to Vercel. This had never happened to me before. It was hapenning at vercel's build time. Upon validation of types to be specific. It wasn't detecting the changes I had made to the prisma.schema that I had updated using ```yarn prisma migrate dev --preview-feature``` . Previously I had never had an issue doing this but maybe I made some mistake along the way.